# Что такое execution context своими словами?

Tags: javascript

Что такое execution context своими словами? *Где* он лежит? Глобальный контекст и глобальный объект - это один и тот же объект? Я так понимаю, это объект какой-то, в котором есть свойства this, variableObject, scopeChain.

Везде при объяснении этого дела просто пишут это

```js
executionContextObj = {
   variableObject: { /* объект активации - состоит из параметров функции, внутренних переменных и объявлений функций */ },
   scopeChain: { /* цепочка областей видимости - объект активации + все объекты активации родительских контекстов выполнения */ },
   this: {}
}
```

И больше ничего не объясняют. А где (внутри какого объекта) этот объект executionContextObj  лежит - не понятно.

Если у меня глобальный объект window, то это можно представить так?

```js
window = {
  variableObject: { /* объект активации - состоит из параметров функции, внутренних переменных и объявлений функций */ },
  scopeChain: { /* цепочка областей видимости - объект активации + все объекты активации родительских контекстов выполнения */ },
  this: {}
}
```

this - достается, если напишу

```js
<script>console.log(window.this);</script>
```

а свойства variableObject и scopeChain - *Не* достаются, если писать

```js
<script>console.log(window.variableObject );</script>
```

Comment: _Везде при объяснении этого дела просто пишут это_ - где например? Откуда вообще предположение, что из скрипта есть доступ к execution context? Что вообще в данном вопросе понимается под execution context?

Comment: взять того же Сошникова. у него так написано, но не объясняется подробно. я не знаю, что такое execution context, поэтому и задал вопрос. понятно только то, что это какой-то объект, а где он находится - мне не понятно. предположение взялось оттуда, что я же могу достать свойство this, почему бы не достать и другие - variableObject и scopeChain

Comment: Стоит добавить ссылку на определение

Comment: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/ru-chapter-1-execution-contexts/

Comment: а ничего, что по ссылке дано следующее определение: _Контекст исполнения (Execution context, сокращённо — EC) – это **абстрактное понятие**, используемое спецификацией ECMA, для типизации и разграничения исполняемого кода._

Comment: хоть абстрактная, хоть неабстрактная - мне все равно эта модель не понятна. бывают вещи абстрактные и понятные, а бывают, как сейчас, абстрактные и НЕпонятные. я понимаю, что это просто модель

Answer (score 2):

Если обратиться к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-execution-contexts):

> An execution context is purely a specification mechanism and need not correspond to any particular artefact of an ECMAScript implementation. *It is **impossible** for ECMAScript code to directly access or observe an execution context*.

---

> Контекст выполнения это только механизм спецификации и не обязательно соответствует чему-то конкретному в реализации ECMAScript. *Для кода ECMAScript **невозможен** прямой доступ или наблюдение за контекстом выполнения.*

Примеры объектов, упоминаемых в вопросе, приведены **только** для общего понимания, что хранится на этом уровне. Никакой связи с реальной реализацией в движках может и не быть.

Одним из примеров реализации можно считать [класс `Context`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/contexts.h#L330) движка v8.

Answer (score 0):

> Что такое execution context своими словами?

Итак, Execution Context. В дальнейшем я могу называть его и Execution Context, и Контекст Выполнения, и ЭК, и КВ. Для краткости, разумеется.

Что говорит по этому поводу спецификация?

> An execution context is a specification device that is used to track
>   the runtime evaluation of code by an ECMAScript implementation.

Прежде всего, ЭК - это абстракция. Это некая сущность, существующая исключительно в рамках спецификации.

Лично вы никаким образом не можете создать Контекст Выполнения и тем более взаимодействовать с ним.

Все, что написано в спецификации относится не напрямую к тому коду, что вы пишете (тем более, что пишете вы JavaScript, для которого вообще отдельный стандарт есть), а относится к ECMAScript-**имплементациям**. То есть к тому, что эту спецификацию **реализовывает** (= имплементирует).

Например, "V8" - JavaScript движок Chrome'а - является имплементацией спецификации ECMAScript.

> Где он лежит?

Там, докуда вы добраться из своего кода никак не можете. Более того, он может и вовсе не "лежать". То есть Execution Context может быть не реализован от слова совсем:

> An execution context is purely a specification mechanism and need not
>   correspond to any particular artefact of an ECMAScript implementation.
>   It is impossible for ECMAScript code to directly access or observe an
>   execution context.

Самое главное для имплементации - это правильность исполнения кода, который эта имплементация должна исполнять, а не сам код этой имплементации (то есть ее исходный текст).

Иными словами, Контекст Выполнения может быть не реализован тем же движком V8 явно (например, в виде класса `ExecutionContext`), а вместо этого может быть реализован лишь **функционал**, описанный как обязательный минимум того, что должен представлять из себя Контекст Выполнения как механизм спецификации.

> Глобальный контекст и глобальный объект - это один и тот же объект? Я
>   так понимаю, это объект какой-то, в котором есть свойства this,
>   variableObject, scopeChain.

Первая часть утверждения в корне неверна.

Существует глобальный Контекст Выполнения (он же глобальный контекст). Это тот контекст, в контексте которого исполняется глобальный код, то есть код верхнего уровня скрипта. Например, при подключении к странице файла `main.js`:

```
// html
<script src="main.js"></script>

// main.js
Именно здесь, в самом верхнем уровне скрипта вы пишете код, исполнение которого будет происходить в контексте глобального Контекста Выполнения.
```

С другой стороны существует [глобальный объект](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-global-object), доступ к которому предоставляется при обращении к идентификатору `this` в *глобальном контексте*:

> // все тот же main.js console.log(this); // - тот самый глобальный
>   объект.

Помимо `this` спецификация также разрешает имплементациям хранить ссылку на глобальный объект в самом глобальном объекте. В браузерах так и есть. Свойство `window` глобального объекта ссылается на сам глобальный объект:

```
console.log(this.window === this); // true
```

> Я так понимаю, это объект какой-то, в котором есть свойства this,
>   variableObject, scopeChain.

А уже вот эта часть чуть более похожа на правду. Но все равно до конца не верна.

Во-первых, непонятно, к чему относится "объект". Мы уже выяснили, что глобальный контекст не равен глобальному объекту. Поэтому дальше буду считать, что слово "объект" использовано по отношению к глобальному контексту.

> в котором есть свойства this, variableObject, scopeChain.

Сразу оговорюсь про scopeChain. Вопрос был задан тогда, когда той версии спецификации, о которой говорю я (8-ой), еще не существовало. Возможно, в предыдущих версиях и существовал некий компонент `scopeChain` Контекста Выполнения, однако об этом я ничего не знаю (да и сомневаюсь, что оно действительно так). Более того, я думаю, что это *не* так, но в любом случае эту часть я опущу, потому как в современной редакции ECMAScript никакого scopeChain не определено (не определено **явно**, хотя в принципе понятно, о чем идет речь. Просто это выходит за рамки моего ответа).

Теперь о `this`. Значение биндинга `this` действительно зависит от того, код *какого* Контекста Выполнения исполняется. Вернее от того, какой тип имеет Лексическое Окружение текущего Контекста Выполнения. Но поскольку рассматривать Лексические Окружения в данном ответе я не буду (по понятным причинам), то просто скажу, что значение `this` определяется состоянием соответствующего интринсика Записи Окружения того Лексического Окружения, которое ассоциировано с текущим Контекстом Выполнения.

А вот сам VariableEnvironment (VE) наравне с LexicalEnvironment (LE) действительно являются составляющими любого ЭК. Точнее, сами по себе они являются отдельными сущностями (Лексическими Окружениями), а VE и LE - это конкретные *записи* Контекста Выполнения, представленные этими "сущностями".

> Везде при объяснении этого дела просто пишут это [дальше код]

Те, кто так пишут просто пытаются *абстрактно* представить реальным кодом то, как *может* выглядеть реализация (точнее, скорее реальная "запись" в уже готовой реализации) Контекста Выполнения.

Не забивайте себе этим голову. Никаким образом невозможно достучаться (работать, манипулировать, изменять, да просто банально прочитать) до Контекста Выполнения, потому как, напоминаю, его может не существовать как такового даже на уровне реализации, не говоря уже о каком-то реальном JavaScript коде, который вы пишете.

### Так когда же они создаются, эти Контексты Выполнения?

Часть, в которой я (уже в третий раз) напоминаю о том, что они могут и не создаваться имплементацией вовсе, опустим. Вместо этого посмотрим на примеры реального кода, в которых создается новый ЭК ***с точки зрения спецификации***.

```
function foo() {}
foo();
```

Пожалуйста. Новый Контекст выполнения создается для выполнения любой функции.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Пожалуйста (2). К сожалению, я не могу изобразить "вызов" подключенного скрипта (хотя бы потому, что вызов происходит на уровне браузера). Однако это не отменяет того факта, что ЭК создается для выполнения любого вида работ (например, для исполнения целого скрипта). Кроме того, как уже рассматривалось выше, такой ЭК будет являться глобальным Контекстом Выполнения.

Проще говоря, новый Контекст Выполнения создается имплементацией (явно или неявно) каждый раз при начале выполнения какого-то кода, который не ассоциирован ни с одним другим Контекстом Выполнения:

> A new execution context is created whenever control is transferred
>   from the executable code associated with the currently running
>   execution context to executable code that is not associated with that
>   execution context.

### Подводя итоги

Самое основное и главное, что вы должны понять: **Контекст Выполнения существует только как абстрактный механизм, определяемый спецификацией** для того, чтобы она могла опираясь на него описывать некие свои алгоритмы.

Создать Контекст Выполнения явно (например, при помощи какого-то API) не представляется возможным хотя бы исходя из написанного абзацем выше.

Обратиться и манипулировать составляющими Контекста Выполнения в реальном JavaScript коде также нельзя.

---

Этот ответ основан на мыслях, [изложенных в написанной мною ранее статье](https://medium.com/@g.smellyshovel/the-ecmascript-executable-code-and-execution-contexts-chapter-explained-fa6e098e230f#27f0) на аналогичную тематику. В рамках этого ответа всего не изложишь и не растолкуешь. Поэтому настоятельно рекомендую заинтересовавшимся прочесть больше в статье по приведенной ссылке. В частности, про [Лексические Окружения](https://medium.com/@g.smellyshovel/the-ecmascript-executable-code-and-execution-contexts-chapter-explained-fa6e098e230f#1d49), их [записи](https://medium.com/@g.smellyshovel/the-ecmascript-executable-code-and-execution-contexts-chapter-explained-fa6e098e230f#d0b6) и про [глобальный объект](https://medium.com/@g.smellyshovel/the-ecmascript-executable-code-and-execution-contexts-chapter-explained-fa6e098e230f#229e).